# In a project with mixed XML and annotation hibernate entities, which is scanned first?

Tags: java, hibernate

We are working on a project with hibernate 4.2.21 with mixed XML-based entities and annotation-based entities. The question is:
Which entities are scanned first?
In other words,
If EntityA is XML based entity and EntityB is annotation bases one. Can EntityA have the property of type EntityB?

Comment: I don't _think_ it matters; Hibernate is building up an in-memory model and then performs consistency checks once it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix up entities mapped via annotations and entities mapped via XML.

From the Hibernate documentation (emphasis mine):

> You can mix annotated persistent classes and classic hbm.cfg.xml
> declarations with the same SessionFactory. You can however not declare
> a class several times (whether annotated or through hbm.xml). **You**
> **cannot mix configuration strategies (hbm vs annotations) in an entity
> hierarchy either.**

Comment: Thanks for the declaration, but which entities loaded first XML based or annotation-based?

Comment: This does not seem to be documented, may I ask why you want to know?

Comment: Actually `hibernate.mapping.precedence` can be used in case classes are mapped with annotations AND XML, so it might also affect the scanning order.

Comment: I'm working on a project where the entities mapping is mixed. Annotation-based entities can have a property of type XML-based entity. But at some point, I needed an XML-based entity to have a property of type annotation-based and it didn't work. I was trying to know if it didn't work because it doesn't suppose to work or I did something wrong so I need to figure it out.

Comment: It should work, maybe try to edit your question with the problem you're facing